# How to remove double quotation when using JSON

Tags: javascript

How can I replace this `"sample"` to `sample` using replace in javascript.

I tried `t=t.replace("""," ");`

Comment: Doing this can potentially break your JSON if you have strings within possibly containing double quotes (or user-entered-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample = '"sample"'.match(/[^"]+/g)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `"` in a string delimited by `"` then you have to escape it:

```
"\""
```

However, if you want to replace multiple times, you need to use a regular expression with the global flag.

```
t=t.replace(/"/g," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following to replace quotes to blank:

`str = str.replace(/"/g, "");`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the global flag:

```
var name = "\"Ahmad\"";
console.log(name);
console.log(name.replace(/\"/g, ""));  

// "Ahmad"
// Ahmad
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

str = str.replace(/(")/, "");

or

str = str.replace(/\"/, "");